# Ethereum contract, running a function corrupts contract members

Tags: solidity

I made a simple contract that stores ether and then can send ether. The function that sends ether has a requirement that only the owner of the contract can send ether from the contract.

The contract mysteriously fails to send ether every subsequent call after the first.

I created a function to retrieve the owner address value in the contract and it turns out that after the first function call, it changes the data to `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000a`

Sending function:

```
function SendToAddress (uint8 amt, address adr) isOwner {
    /* Have we transferred over the maximum amount in
       the last 24 hours? */
    if ((now - dayStartTime) >= secondsInADay) {
        dayStartTime = now;
        curDayTransfer = 0;
    }
    if ((curDayTransfer + amt) < dayMaxTransfer) {
        adr.transfer (amt);
        walletBalance -= amt;   
        curDayTransfer += amt;
        MoneyTransfer newTransfer;
        newTransfer.amount = amt;
        newTransfer.target = adr;
        newTransfer.timeStamp = now;


        if (transferHistory.length == 100) {
            // Shift all of the transactions in the history list forward
            //   to make space for the transaction. 
            for (uint8 i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                transferHistory[i] = transferHistory[i-1];
            }
            transferHistory[0] = newTransfer;
        } else {
            transferHistory.push (newTransfer);
        } 

    }
}
```

isOwner modifier:

```
modifier isOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == creatorAddress);
    _;
}
```

constructor:

```
constructor () public {
    creatorAddress = msg.sender;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the compiler gives you a warning on the line `MoneyTransfer newTransfer;` about implicitly storing the data in `storage`. If you explicitly use `MoneyTransfer storage newTransfer;`, then you'll get a warning that you're using an uninitialized storage reference. That means whatever values you put in `newTransfer` will overwrite whatever's in the first few storage slots.

Use `MoneyTransfer memory newTransfer;` instead.

Comment: Yes I printed debug events and it seems like the object was causing problems, will try this, thanks